# Convert ZonedDateTime to end of the day

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, zoneddatetime

In this code,

```
Instant i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(inputDate);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instance, ZoneId.of(marketplaceIdToZoneMap.get(timeZone)));
```

I just want this time zoneDateTime to be end of the day,

like if value of zonedDateTime is : 2019-11-14 12:00:99

Output should come as 2019-11-14 23:59:59

Comment: Not only has this question been asked before, it has also been answered with some very good answers. Please check the link to the original question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want the last second of the day, you can use:

```
ZonedDateTime eod = zonedDateTime.with(LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
```

If you want the maximum time of the day, you can use:

```
ZonedDateTime eod = zonedDateTime.with(LocalTime.MAX);
```

Note that there are weird situations where 23:59:59 may not be a valid time for a specific day (typically historical days with complicated timezone changes).

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution is to manually set the values you want:

```
zonedDateTime.withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59);
```

Another solution could be to reset the hours/minutes/second, add one day, and remove one second:

```
zonedDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plusDay(1).minusSecond(1);
```